# Best way: talend interfaces from VPC to WWW

Tags: amazon-web-services, interface, aws-lambda, talend

For an interface from our VPC to a FTP Server in the WWW we think about realizing it with talend. From our Security Officer and some other sources I heard that connecting from a VPC via talend to a source in the WWW is not the best idea. So we came up with two other versions:

- Put a microservice in between
- Use a lambda function and let the
  function put the data into a bucket

From security & cost & efficiency perspective I think V3 would be the best idea but maybe someone else experienced something different or having even a better idea?

[image]

Comment: What is your use case here? Ingest files from SFTP and store the data in BigQuery? Also, could you elaborate on "not the best idea"? What exactly did they say, what were their arguments against your initial proposal?

Comment: The question here is: Is it secured? S3, Big Query, etc is in our VPC. But how can we be sure that the lambda function and the connect to the SFTP is secured and encytped?

Comment: I get the feeling that you need a deeper understanding about what SFTP is and how it works to answer your questions. V1 is a totally valid solution, as long as your fine to store the SFTP credentials inside AWS (which you would need to do anyway if you want to run Talend on AWS). Just adding more layers won't help if you don't trust the security of your SFTP connection.